# How to properly export variables in node.js module to make it visible for unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to unit test node.js modules, I'd like to know how to export varibles and objects properly? So I can access them in my Unit Test and work on them.

source code:

```
var someObject = {};

var Array = [189, 347, 497, 632, 750, 900, 995, 1137],
    someNumber = 142,
    sizeOfArray = Allowance.length; 

someObject = { 

    method1 : function (info) {
         //something...
         return {
             someOtherMethod1: someObject.method1(info) && someObject.method2(info)
             someOtherMethod2: someObject.method3(info)
         };
    },

    method2 : function (info) {
        //something...

        return something2;
    } 

    method3 : function (info) {
        //something...

        return something3;
    }
};

module.exports = someObject;
```

So by doing:

```
module.exports = someObject;
```

I am able to access someObject in a unit test file in mocha, but how can I access the other variables like Array, sizeOfArray, someNumber?

I've tried adding this:

```
module.exports = {

      someObject  : someObject,
      Array       : Array,
      someNumber  : someNumber,
      sizeOfArray : sizeOfArray
};
```

But my unit test file cannot read it

**Edit:**

*Here is my unit test*

```
var assert = require("assert") 
var expect = require("expect.js") 
var chai   = require("chai")  

var sourceCode = require('../src/sourceCode') 


  describe("Something..", function() { 

      var Info = { 
        //some data...
      };


      describe("Properties", function() { 

          it("has someObject defined", function() {
            expect(someObject).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has Array defined", function() {
            expect(Array).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has someNumber defined", function() {
            expect(someNumber).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has sizeOfArray defined", function() {
            expect(sizeOfArray).not.to.be.undefined; 
          })

        })

  describe("Methods", function() {

      it("should have method1 defined", function() { 
       expect(sourceCode.someObject.method1(Info)).not.to.be.undefined;
      });

      it("should have method2 defined", function() { 
        expect(sourceCode.someObject.method2(Info)).not.to.be.undefined; 
      });
  })

    };
```

@Augusto

**This is what I was talking about for testing Method1**

```
it("should return positive when conditions are met", function() {

        var result = sourceCode.someObject.method1(Info);

        expect(result).not.to.be.undefined;
        expect(result.eligible).not.to.be.undefined;
        expect(sourceCode.result.someOtherMethod2).not.to.be.undefined;

        expect(sourceCode.result.someOtherMethod1).to.equal(true);
});
```

Comment: That code will work.  Show us your unit test.

Comment: It tells me all those variables are undefined...meaning they aren't able to be accessed. I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your unit tests. You are not accessing the properties in the object

```
var sourceCode = require('../src/sourceCode');

//CODE CODE CODE

expect(Array).not.to.be.undefined;
```

There you were trying to access the *Array* variable instead of the *sourceCode.Array* property. As you were not defining an *Array* variable you were getting the undefined error message. The correct code would've been:

```
expect(sourceCode.Array).not.to.be.undefined;
```

So.. in your unit tests try this:

```
var assert = require("assert") 
var expect = require("expect.js") 
var chai   = require("chai")  

var sourceCode = require('../src/sourceCode') 


  describe("Something..", function() { 

      var Info = { 
        //some data...
      };


      describe("Properties", function() { 

          it("has someObject defined", function() {
            expect(sourceCode.someObject).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has Array defined", function() {
            expect(sourceCode.Array).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has someNumber defined", function() {
            expect(sourceCode.someNumber).not.to.be.undefined; 
          });

          it("has sizeOfArray defined", function() {
            expect(sourceCode.sizeOfArray).not.to.be.undefined; 
          })

        })
    };
```

Comment: I did exactly what you specified, the variables work now, but the methods of someObject still don't work...Am I doing the methods correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to test that the methods are undefined or the method's return value are undefined?... because if you want to the the first option then you shoud be doing expect(sourceCode.someObject.method1).not.to.be.undefined;

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing but I've given it parameter which I made in the test itself. I'm trying to verify the existance of these methods. I want them to not be undefined. I've added it to my original question. Mocha complains it doesn't recognize these methods, this is soo weird, I know I'm probably making some silly mistake I'm not seeing but what in God's name could it be...

Comment: Well... Ok if that's the case then, for what i can see in your code, you are doing "expect(sourceCode.someObject.method1(Info)).not.to.be.undefined;" when you should be doing "expect(sourceCode.someObject.method1).not.to.be.undefined;"

Comment: You fixed it!! Thank you! What if say...I added another method to the source code, what could I do to test that, like testing if that method returns true when it's conditions are met       it("should return positive when conditions are met", function() {
varresult=sourceCode.someObject.method1(Info);expect(result).not.to.be.undefined;expect(result.eligible).not.to.be.undefined;expect(sourceCode.result.someOtherMethod2).not.to.be.undefined;expect(sourceCode.result.someOtherMethod1).to.equal(true);}); ----**Sorry I added this in my original question so you can see it properly formatted**

Comment: For hwta i can see there you are doing it properly. I think that a mistake could come for the fact thar your are testing against sourceCode.result instead of just test against result. sourceCode.result is undefined always.